# Tilde breaks the reference

Tags: python-sphinx

I have at the top of a module:

```py
"""
Constructs the :any:`Server` object and invokes its :any:`~Server.run` method.
"""
```

The second reference gives the warning: `WARNING: 'any' reference target not found: ~Server.run`. If I remove the tilde, it works just fine. What am I missing?

**UPDATE:** Based on the suggestions in the comments, I tried using `:py:meth` instead of `:any:`. In this case, there is no error, but the text appears in black and is not clickable.

Comment: Quick question - what's the purpose of tilde in documentation? I have not seen its use beore.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa To display only the last part (`run` in this case), while using the whole thing for the actual reference.

Comment: Looks like a bug. This should work according to https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing-syntax

Comment: What happens if you change the directive to `:py:method:`?

Comment: @StevePiercy `Unknown interpreted text role "py:method"`

Comment: The role name is `:py:meth:`: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#role-py-meth. If it does not work either, add that information to the question.

Comment: @mzjn I added the result to the question as per your recommendation.